# Detectlanguage - Fatal Error Uncaught Exception

Tags: php, html, fatal-error

I try to use this github library

https://github.com/detectlanguage/detectlanguage-php

I signed up for an API Key before.

My code is very simple, but throws an uncaught expection immediately:

```
  require_once 'includes/detectlanguage/lib/detectlanguage.php';
  use \DetectLanguage\DetectLanguage;
  DetectLanguage::setApiKey("xxxxxxx7687af9cb91950327ea");
  $languageCode = DetectLanguage::simpleDetect("Hallo und einen schönen Tag"); 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DetectLanguage\Error' with message 'Invalid server response: ' in /var/www/bodo/dokumente-online.com/includes/detectlanguage/lib/DetectLanguage/Client.php:45 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/bodo/dokumente-online.com/includes/detectlanguage/lib/DetectLanguage/DetectLanguage.php(80): DetectLanguage\Client::request('detect', Array) #1 /var/www/bodo/dokumente-online.com/test_detect.php(7): DetectLanguage\DetectLanguage::detect('HAllo und einen...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/xyz.com/includes/detectlanguage/lib/DetectLanguage/Client.php on line 45
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Service seems to work.

Comment: The error indicates that you're not getting a good response back from the API call. Your best bet would be to print or echo out the response from the server and see if it gives any useful information.

Comment: Could you add the output of
 `var_dump(DetectLanguage::getStatus());` after setting the `setApiKey()`, please?

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems to indicate that the server didn't return a JSON body or one that can't be decoded. Since the error doesn't show a body, you're probably getting a 403 status or something similar. `if (!is_object($response))

throw new Error("Invalid server response: $response_body");

`

Comment: the var_dump gives this result: object(stdClass)#1 (8) { ["date"]=> string(10) "2018-12-28" ["requests"]=> int(0) ["bytes"]=> int(0) ["plan"]=> string(4) "FREE" ["plan_expires"]=> NULL ["daily_requests_limit"]=> int(1000) ["daily_bytes_limit"]=> int(1048576) ["status"]=> string(6) "ACTIVE" }